# Include and Extends the same file?

Tags: html, twig

I'm using twig and having a problem with `include` and `extends`.

I have a file header.html.twig that I'm including on index.html.twig.  That works fine.

However, I'm also trying to overwrite a portion of the header.html.twig file with `extends` on index.html.twig.  The code I came up with is:

```
<!-- index.html.twig -->
{% include '::header.html.twig' %}
    {% extends '::header.html.twig' %}
    {% block head %}
        <li class="active"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
    {% endblock %}
```

However, this code throws the exception "A template that extends another one cannot have a body...."

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide some details? What does `header.html.twig` look like? What are you exactly are trying to overwrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have `{% block... %} {% endblock %}` tags in the template that extends another one.

In your case, if I got correctly what you are trying to achieve, you can define an empty block in header.html.twig (at the beginning), and override that block in index.html.twig with

```
{% block foo %}
    {% include "header.html.twig" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing things outside any block, those things are considered to be the body of your twig file. And as the exception clearly tells, if you are extending a twig template, you need to overwrite some blocks contained in the extended file without any body.

You should use the `{% extends %}` tag without any include before, as the extends already include contents. The packaged "base.html.twig" file is a good example: you put the code that will be used everywhere in your application in a base.html.twig file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

For your case, you can add a `{% block head %}{% endblock %}` above the body block, and then, in your index.html.twig file, you'll overwrite this block to fulfill it.

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block head %}
    <li class="active"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
{% endblock %}
```

This will finally output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Welcome!</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <li class="active"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Conclusion

The difference between `extends` and `include` is that you are able to override blocks from the extended file, where you can't while including it using `include`.